# How to avoid post-token code execution in ANTLR, when token is absent?

Tags: java, antlr, antlr4

This is my ANTLR script:

```
greeting:
  'hello'
  NAME
  { /* do something with $NAME.text */ }
  ;
```

This input causes an NPE because `NAME` is null:

```
hello
```

I understand that I can check whether `$NAME` is not null and only then do my manipulations with `$NAME.text`, but I have that problem in many places in the script. Should I always do `if ($NAME != null)` or maybe there is some other more elegant mechanism?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ANTLR 4, you should relocate the embedded actions to a listener or visitor which you separately execute after the parsing phase is complete. You can use the `Parser.getNumberOfSyntaxErrors` method prior to starting that phase to see if any parse errors occurred, and if so, stop processing at that point.

This covers all actions associated with the parser at once and results in a *much* cleaner overall code structure.

Comment: I'm afraid that the code will look more verbose and less cohesive. I'll have my logic distributed in multiple files.. I actually think that the ability to write Java together with grammar/lexical constructs is a great advantage of ANTLR comparing to, say, yacc/flex.

Comment: @yegor256 As an author of some of the most complex tools using ANTLR *anywhere*, I can say with great confidence that your fear is unfounded. If you are concerned about cohesiveness, please take time to read [this email thread](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/antlr-discussion/l8zyGk1Zi28/B7KSAT8wJd0J) and provide feedback regarding the feature proposal.

Comment: This is my [spec.g4](https://github.com/tpc2/requs/blob/requs-1.1/requs-core/src/main/antlr4/org/requs/syntax/Spec.g4). It looks cohesive and clean, isn't it? ANTLR listener would looks huge and won't follow our "OOP strict" design principles.. as far as I can tell now

Comment: @yegor256 To me it looks cluttered, littered with actions irrelevant to the actual parsing. At best, it's extremely difficult to look at rules in that grammar and understand the structure of the language. It only gets worse as the grammar grows, but this [before](https://github.com/sharwell/sensei/blob/9b4dd022/sensei-core/src/main/antlr3/com/senseidb/bql/parsers/BQL.g) and [after](https://github.com/senseidb/sensei/blob/master/sensei-core/src/main/antlr4/com/senseidb/bql/parsers/BQL.g4) shows how much cleaner the grammar really is when you separate the grammar from the action code.